# NTILE function, wrong number of records

Tags: sql, sql-server

Consider this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT x.*
FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT Id,
            VideoId,
            [Date],
            NTILE(2) OVER(ORDER BY VideoId) AS tile_nr
        FROM
            [Database].[dbo].[Table] a
     ) x
WHERE
    CONVERT(Date, [Date]) = CONVERT(Date, GETDATE())
```

The total rows of videos are 3320. With the NTILE function I can divide the list into 2 parts. So when I put an AND at the end like so:

```
AND
    x.tile_nr = 1
```

It will return the first half of the resultset. The problem, or what I believe to be a problem, is that the first resultset contains 1656 records most of the time. But sometimes contain 1657 records. So when I also retrieve the second half of the resultset, the total will end up at 3321 sometimes. How can I avoid this from happening?

Comment: Is VideoId `unique` in `[Table]`?

Comment: I don't think that `VideoId` is `unique`, I suggest you paginating them using RANK function.

Comment: @LuisLL Yes they are unique.

Comment: @MartinSmith Ah forgot to remove, was just for testing purposes.

Comment: so is it working as expected now, or is there still a problem?

Comment: @Rikalous The problem exists

Comment: It looks to me that you are dividing your data in half and *then* applying a condition (the WHERE), this is not likely to generate two equal sized sets.

Comment: @Rikalous Moving the first condition into the subselect fixed the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the BOL entry for NTile you will see the below comment, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175126.aspx.

> If the number of rows in a partition is not divisible by
>   integer_expression, this will cause groups of two sizes that differ by
>   one member. Larger groups come before smaller groups in the order
>   specified by the OVER clause. For example if the total number of rows
>   is 53 and the number of groups is five, the first three groups will
>   have 11 rows and the two remaining groups will have 10 rows each. If
>   on the other hand the total number of rows is divisible by the number
>   of groups, the rows will be evenly distributed among the groups. For
>   example, if the total number of rows is 50, and there are five groups,
>   each bucket will contain 10 rows.

With that said, you may have to persist your results in a temp table because the row count could change between multiple executions and you can end up with differing groups/totals.  If you go back to the temp table rather than going back to the base tables, you can guarantee the data will be the same.